# Worksheet <Worksheet "Tabelle1"> does not exist

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to remove a Worksheet from my Workbook with the Python module openpyxl.

```
def delete_sheet_name(self, input, sheetname):
    wb:Workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(input)


    test = list()

    test = wb.sheetnames
    print(test)
    print(type(test))
    std = wb.get_sheet_by_name(wb["Tabelle1"])

    for elem in test:
        if "Abschätzung" not in elem:
            print(elem)

    wb.remove(std)
    wb.save(input)
    wb.close()
```

I attempt to get the error "KeyError: 'Worksheet <Worksheet "Tabelle1"> does not exist.'", but the Worksheet exists!

Comment: I got the answear, because of wb.get_sheet_by_name(wb["Tabelle1"]) is deprecated, you can only make it with this line of code : wb.remove(wb["Tabelle1"])

Comment: `wb.get_sheet_by_name(wb["Tabelle1"])` tries to combine two methods that do the same thing. `wb["Tabelle1"]` already returns the worksheet, which you can't use to look itself up.